# How to estimate uncertainties in class probabilities (or weights W) for SGDClassifier/Logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have a binary classification task, that I fit using SGDClassifier with log loss. For prediction, I am interested in class probabilities (predict_proba) rather than just class labels.

I need to have an estimate of uncertainties on these probabilities, say, on that of positive class, i.e:

```
                     p(x|positive_class) = p0 +/- delta
```

p0 is given as predict_proba(x)[0], but is there a way to have an estimate of delta?

Another way I can think of this is through having uncertainties of weights W and using logistic function p=1/[1+exp(-W.x)] in order to propagate the uncertainty from W to p?

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
p(x|positive_class)
```

is a probability of **generating** sample x, thus you need **generative model** for this. LR is **discriminative** model, and SGD is not a model but a way of learning it (but loss functions implemented in SGDClassifier in sklearn are all discriminative).

You probably want to find out

```
p(positive_class|x) = A +/- eps
```

and unfortunately, the answer is **you cannot**. Models like this **do not provide confidence intervals**. You can do one of the two things:

- train a different model, which provides it directly, like **Gaussian process**
- build a meta model using your classifier as a building block, for example you can train an ensemble of LRs, each on the subset (with resampling) of the training data, and use a set of predictions to estimate confidence intervals (by assuming normal distribution of errors and simply reporting var(p_i(positive_class|x)) over models p_i)